# Timer in status bar (ionic and cordova)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, apk

In my app, a timer will be running in the UI. I wish to show that timer at the status bar.
How to implement dynamic status bar which runs a timer in the notification center parallely?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's best if you try something first and then ask for help if you are having trouble with a certain part of the code and not expect others to do the coding for you.

Comment: ya i have tried such as to overwrite the previous notification every time.but i cannot run the timer separately in notification center.I could find only such method while i searched

Comment: I don't ask for the entire code, just need to know whether it is possible with ionic/cordova and how?